# How to split path into subpaths based on relationship's type?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following graph:

```
(:Stop)<-[:IS_LOCATED_AT]-(:Stoptime)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(:Trip),
(:Stop)<-[:IS_LOCATED_AT]-(:Stoptime)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(:Trip)
(:Stop)-[:TRANSFER]->(:Stop)
(st1:Stoptime)-[:CONNECTION]->(st2:Stoptime)
```

`:Stop` has property `stop_id`.

`:Trip` has properties `startValidDate`, `endValidDate`, `tripExceptions`. Trip is valid only for certain weekdays. These days are represented as properties, for example: `monday: true, sunday: false`. Each Trip has two stoptimes (departure and arrival).

`:Stoptime` can have the following properties:
if the stoptime is departure event (like `st1`), the `:Stoptime` has property `depatureTine`, in other case the st`:Stoptime` optime has property `arrivalTime`.

Every `:Stoptime` has `st_id`.

`[:CONNECTION]` and `[:TRANSFER]` have property `duration`.

In the following query, I try to find paths between two `:Stop`:

```
MATCH (o:Stop)<-[:IS_LOCATED_AT]-(sto:Stoptime)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(tro:Trip)
WHERE o.stop_id=1000001
AND tro.startValidDate<"2019-04-25"
AND tro.endValidDate>"2019-04-25"
AND NOT "2019-04-25" IN tro.tripExceptions
AND tro.thursday=true
WITH sto, o
MATCH (d:Stop)<-[:IS_LOCATED_AT]-(std:Stoptime)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(trd:Trip)
WHERE d.stop_id=1000004
AND trd.startValidDate<"2019-04-25"
AND trd.endValidDate>"2019-04-25"
WITH sto, std, o
MATCH p=((sto)-[*]-(std))
WHERE NOT o IN nodes(p)
AND NONE (y in relationships(p) WHERE type(y)="IS_PART_OF")
RETURN p
```

And this query works well. But I have to check in the case when the path includes relationships `[:TRANSFER]`, if the next Trip is valid for the arrival day.

For example, I have the path after the querying:

```
path=((sta1:Stoptime)-[c:CONNECTION]->(sta2:Stoptime)-[:IS_LOCATED_AT]->(s1:Stop)-[t:TRANSFER]->(s2:Stop)<-[:IS_LOCATED_AT]-(std3:Stoptime)-[:CONNECTION]->(sta2:Stoptime))
```

with:

```
(sta1:Stoptime)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(a:Trip)
(sta2:Stoptime)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(a:Trip)
(stb1:Stoptime)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(b:Trip)
(stb2:Stoptime)-[:IS_PART_OF]->(b:Trip)
```

The route starts on Thursday. I have to check:

```
if (x in relationships(path) WHERE type(z)="TRANSFER"):
    if (the sum of duration of all connections between previous stoptimes + duration of transfer > 24) AND (b.friday=true): return path
    else if (b.thursday=true): return path
else return null
```

I don't know, how I can to write this in Cypher. Or it will be better to go throw all paths in the business layer and check this condition?

I thought, maybe it will be better to split the path into subpaths between transfers?